# Finding Chassis Type Using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winapi, int, wmi, output

I'm trying to find the chassis types of various computers using VB.NET. This is going to be part of an automated testing program that uses certain criteria to determine a routine. The code I am using is as follows

```
'REFERENCING WIN32_SystemEnclosure
Dim qwin32SystemEnclosure As New SelectQuery("Win32_SystemEnclosure")
Dim searchse As New ManagementObjectSearcher(qwin32SystemEnclosure)
Dim infose As New ManagementObject

For Each infose In searchse.Get
    strCOMM = infose("chassisTypes").ToString
Next
```

And I receive `system.Uint16[]` as a result. I know that I am using the right `win_32 class`. I believe there is something wrong with the output going to the string, but I can not figure out how to correct. For reference, the correct output should be 10.

I appreciate the help!

EDIT: I'm having trouble with a similar issue... I am not able to convert uint32 into string or integer like I was able to with uint16 values. Here is my code

```
Imports System.Management
Public Class frmBatterytest
Dim strDesigncap As String
Dim strCurrentcap As String
Dim strResult As String = 0
Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTest.Click
    ' REFERENCING WIN32_BATTERY
    Dim qwin32 As New SelectQuery("Win32_Battery")
    Dim search As New ManagementObjectSearcher(qwin32)
    Dim info As New ManagementObject

    For Each info In search.Get
        strDesigncap = info("DesignCapacity")(0).ToString
        strCurrentcap = info("FullChargeCapacity")(0).ToString
    Next

    lblDCv.Text = strDesigncap
    lblCCv.Text = strCurrentcap
    lblTRv.Text = strCurrentcap / strDesigncap * 100 & "%"

End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: What result are you getting? Are you getting errors? Please elaborate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"system.Uint16[]"` is the result of calling `ToString` on an array type, it will not automatically format the values *in* the array and return them as a string to you.

Pull a specific value:

```
 strCOMM = infose("chassisTypes")(0).ToString
```

Or `Join()` to get all values in a delimited string.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help. I'm not well versed in different data types, and originally did not realize it was formatted as an array.

Comment: I'm having more trouble with this. I wrote a test program to try out some code I'd like to add to my large testing program, but now I'm having issues converting a uint32 to string. The same method that was used to pull the first entry of the uint16 is not working. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you have a uint variable as opposed to an array just `somestring = theuint.ToString`

Comment: I believe that is what I'm trying to do. I posted the code up top. The error I'm getting is:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Additional information: Object variable or With block variable not set."

I'm trying to find answers via MSDN, but it says to just use ".tostring" toconvert uint to string. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If `info("Description").ToString` gives you a null ref exception then `info("Description")` is null, you will need to test for that

Comment: Thanks, I was just going to come on here and update because I realized these were returning null. Thanks, and sorry for the trouble.